# running random characters in the same string

Tags: javascript, callback

As title. I tried the following javascript.

This will console.log() the same random number 20 times, but how do I go about 20 random characters? Are we using callback function?

```js
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
var insert = letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length));

var str = "0";

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    var newStr = str.replace(/./, insert);
    console.log(newStr)
  }, 50 * i)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
var insert = letters.charAt( Math.floor(Math.random()*letters.length) );
```

runs once and once only. It does not re-run the random part every time you ask for the value of `insert`.

You could rerun it manually every loop:

```js
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
var str = "0";
for(i=0; i<20; i++) {

    setTimeout(function(){
      var insert = letters.charAt( Math.floor(Math.random()*letters.length) );
      var newStr = str.replace(/./, insert);
      console.log(newStr)
    }, 50*i)

}
```

But keep in mind that you might get the same character more than once, as by definition it is (pseudo) random - and therefore could pick the same character as has been previously picked.

To ensure you get a *distinct* random character each time you would have to remove a picked character from the list. Easier to do by converting the characters to an array and using `splice` to remove it once selected:

```js
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".split("");
var str = "0";
for(i=0; i<20; i++) {

    setTimeout(function(){
      var insert = Math.floor(Math.random()*letters.length);
      var newStr = str.replace(/./, letters[insert]);
      console.log(newStr)
      letters.splice(insert,1);
    }, 50*i)

}
```

Comment: Ugh...I see, such a stupid question. This pseudo random string would serve the purpose. Thank you so much for the help!